# Requesting clarity on understanding parentElement more clearly

Tags: javascript

Although my code works and I understand all of it, what I am stumped on is why parentElement works for the code below.

By my understanding, the parent element of the button element should be the div with class "child-div", so why then is the code still giving me the correct answer for each "shop-item-title" when clicking the "Okay" button?

Any clarity will be highly appreciated:

```js
let addToCart = document.getElementsByClassName("button-ok");

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  let button = event.target;
  let shopItem = button.parentElement;
  let title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-title")[0].innerText;
  console.log(title);
}

for (let i = 0; i < addToCart.length; i++) {
  let button = addToCart[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", addToCartClicked);
}
```

```html
<div class="body-container">
  <div class="child-div">
    <p class="shop-item-title">Chocolate</p>
    <br />
    <button class="button-ok">Okay</button>
  </div>

  <div class="child-div">
    <p class="shop-item-title">Coke</p>
    <br />
    <button class="button-ok">Okay</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"the parent element of the button element should be the div with class `body-container`"_... what makes you think that? The parent element of each button is a `<div class="child-div">` element

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I seemed to have made an error when typing it out. In that case, if the parent element of shopItem is "child-div", how does the code still work? Shouldn't it only work if the parentElement was "shop-item-title"?

Comment: You get the `parentElement` which returns a `<div class="child-div">` and assign it to `shopItem`. You then get the elements with class name `shop-item-title` **within** that `<div class="child-div">` element when you call `shopItem.getElementsByClassName("shop-item-title")`

Comment: Oh! Okay that's a perfect explanation. I think that definitely helps me understand the code better. Thank you for your help. It is definitely highly appreciated.